# Code to detect hidden rows, unhide them, and apply border

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using this bit of VBA code to detect hidden rows on a spreadsheet. On top of this, I want it to unhide those rows and highlight the cells in the previously hidden row from columns A to W with a red border.

```
Sub ShowRows()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Dim sTemp As String

    Set rng = Range("A1:A1000")
    sTemp = ""
    For Each r In rng.Rows
        If r.EntireRow.Hidden Then
            sTemp = sTemp & "Row " & Mid(r.Address, 4) & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next r

     If sTemp > "" Then
        sTemp = "The following rows are hidden:" & vbCrLf & _
          vbCrLf & sTemp
          MsgBox sTemp
     Else
         MsgBox "There are no hidden rows."
     End If 
End Sub
```

Edit: Sorry. I forgot to mention that a later part of this script applies some conditional formatting to all rows. Whether this part of this script comes before or after that, I suppose it doesn't matter. But I don't want this to take the place of other formatting, just add to it by applying a border.

Comment: @scottcraner - Hey! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111528/vba-lounge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
Sub ShowRows()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Dim sTemp As String

    Set rng = Range("A1:A1000")
    sTemp = ""
    For Each r In rng.Rows
        If r.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
            sTemp = sTemp & "Row " & Mid(r.Address, 4) & vbCrLf
            r.EntireRow.Hidden = false
                With Range("A" & r.Row & ":W" & r.Row).Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
                     .Color = -16776961
                     .Weight = xlMedium
                End With

                With Range("A" & r.Row & ":W" & r.Row).Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                     .Color = -16776961
                     .Weight = xlMedium
                End With

                With Range("A" & r.Row & ":W" & r.Row).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                     .Color = -16776961
                     .Weight = xlMedium
                End With

                With Range("A" & r.Row & ":W" & r.Row).Borders(xlEdgeRight)
                     .Color = -16776961
                     .Weight = xlMedium
                End With
        End If
    Next r

     If sTemp <> "" Then
        sTemp = "The following rows are hidden:" & vbCrLf & _
          vbCrLf & sTemp
          MsgBox sTemp
     Else
         MsgBox "There are no hidden rows."
     End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly, but that destroys the formatting that the row already has. I've changed my question above to apply a border to the row instead of the fill color.

Comment: @Robby There you go!

Comment: Nice. One more thing though: I should have specified in my comment, but the border needs to be red. I can't figure out how to specify the border color AND and the weight. Do they have to be set in different statements?

Comment: @Robby Yup - I've updated to change it to red - Sub-in `xlThin`, `xlMedium`, and `xlThick` to change the thickness

Answer (score 0):

Just add lines to unhide and colour the rows in your rows loop

```
Sub ShowRows()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim sTemp2 As String

    Set rng = Range("A1:A1000")
    sTemp = ""
    For Each r In rng.Rows
        If r.EntireRow.Hidden Then
            sTemp = sTemp & "Row " & Mid(r.Address, 4) & vbCrLf
            r.Hidden = False
            sTemp2 = "A" & Mid(r.Address, 4) & ":H" & Mid(r.Address, 4)
            Range(sTemp2).Borders.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next r

     If sTemp > "" Then
         sTemp = "The following rows are hidden:" & vbCrLf & _
         vbCrLf & sTemp
         MsgBox sTemp
     Else
         MsgBox "There are no hidden rows."
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly, but that destroys the formatting that the row already has. I've changed my question above to apply a border to the row instead of the fill color.